# Cosa significa "l'altro giorno avevo il mio gatto..."?

Tags: phrases

Questa è una frase che lo sento tanto in giro, non so se è completamente Informale o segue qualche regola grammatica?

Comment: Cosa ti colpisce di questa frase? Significa quello che letteralmente dice.

Comment: Ok, si è vero, grazie

Comment: Mai sentita, e suona pure un po' strana (adesso non lo ha più, il gatto?). L'hai sentita usare in qualche modo specifico (citazione, proverbio...) o tra gente che parla normalmente di gatti?

Comment: No no,  si parlava così: l'altro giorno avevo il gatto che saliva sui divani...

Comment: Ah, d'accordo. Sì, in effetti è un po' colloquiale. In un registro più formale si direbbe qualcosa come “L'altro giorno il mio gatto saliva etc.”

Answer (score 1):

> avevo il gatto che saliva sui divani.

è un espressione colloquiale per indicare che si è osservato il gatto salire sui divani. Non conosco il resto della frase, ma potrebbe anche indicare anche che questo comportamento interferiva in qualche modo con quello che la persona voleva fare, o comunque questa espressione può essere considerata una premessa o un antefatto per il resto del racconto.